# Safari deleting every tab that I open

Tags: iphone, safari

In Safari every time I close the app or turn off my iPhone, every tab that I have open is deleted. I have absolutely no idea how it started, and it deleted a couple important tabs.

Comment: And you did not bookmark them

Comment: I did. But that isn´t really what I was after, I just want it to stop deleting everthing everytime I close down the app. :(

Comment: OK, just checking you did not loose them. So what you want is to keep the history and reload.

Comment: Thank you, but they´re fine! :) How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try..

```
Open Safari

Press and hold the back arrow button on the far left hand side of the bottom tool bar.

Your browser history menu will appear on the screen.
```

From here, you can tap on a link to open it.

Comment: Thank you! But I already know this and use it often because of my problem with Safari deleting everything and such. Thank you, anyways!

Comment: so are the history tabs there or not

Comment: Well, the history is still there. But the app won´t keep any tabs open, that´s kind of the problem.

Comment: That is good, so it remembers them.

Answer (score 1):

This post indicates that the problem can be caused by a build-up of stored website data: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7894860

The recommendation is to clear website data by going to Settings -> Safari -> Advanced (at the bottom) -> Website Data

Then clicking [Remove All Website Data]

The post says that this may have implications for some websites such as having to log in again.